# Is every function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ a composition $f = g\circ g$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations, function-and-relation-composition

> True or wrong: For every function $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ there is a function $g: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ with $f=g \circ g$.

Comment: That's really broad. Is it an automorphism? Permutation? identity mapping?

Comment: Try to do it for the function $f$ that switches $1$ and $2$, but fixes everything else.

Comment: To elaborate on GEdgar's answer, let $g$ be the function that sends $1$ to $2$ and $2$ to $1$ so we have $f : \{1, 2, \dots, n\} \to \{2, 1, \dots, n\}$. Apply it twice.

Comment: @DonLarynx, there are no other extra assumptions, it just has to be $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$.

Comment: Well, intuitionally another example of function that is not a composition would be $f(x)=x^3$, but I'm afraid that i have to proof that there is no possibility to define $f$ as $g \cdot g$.

Comment: @Olaf Do you know any group theory? If so you can restrict your attention to bijections and use group actions to convince yourself that GEdgar really has given you a counter-example.

Comment: @DonLarynx why apply it twice?

Comment: @Rasmus that would be a function that sends the original set to itself; that is, it has order $2\hspace{3 pt} (f^2 = i)$.

Comment: Essentially, take two elements, swap them, and swap them back. That is an example that satisfies OP's requirements

Comment: OK, I see it now, thanks a lot every one, especially GEdgar and Don Larynx.

Comment: @DonLarynx That's not the point. The point is that swapping once cannot be decomposed into the composition of a function with itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the mapping
$$f : \mathbb N\to\mathbb N, x\mapsto\begin{cases}1 & \text{if }x = 2 \\2 & \text{if }x = 1 \\ x & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Assume $g : \mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is a mapping with $f = g\circ g$.

We have $g(1) \neq 1$, because otherwise $f(1) = g(g(1)) = g(1) = 1$.

Furthermore $g(1) \neq 2$, because otherwise $g(2) = g(g(1)) = f(1) = 2$ and thus $f(2) = g(g(2)) = g(2) = 2$.

So $y := g(1) \notin\{1,2\}$ and therefore $f(y) = y$.

We continue with $g(y) = g(g(1)) = f(1) = 2$.

It follows that $g(2) = g(g(y)) = f(y) = y$, so
$$f(1) = g(g(1)) = g(y) = g(g(2)) = f(2).$$
Contradiction.

**Remark**

Based on the above argument, we get the following generalization:

> Let $X$ be a set. It holds that $\lvert X\rvert \leq 1$ if and only if for every function $f : X \to X$, there is a function $g : X\to X$ with $f = g\circ g$.

Comment: About your remark: consider $f:x\mapsto x$ on every set $X$, and $f:n\mapsto n+2$ on $\mathbb Z$. Or perhaps you wish to say that the only sets $X$ such that every $f:X\to X$ has a "square root", are the sets $X$ such that $|X|\leqslant1$?

Comment: @Did: It was a problem of ambiguous bracketing. The two equivalent statements are swapped now to make it unambiguous.

Comment: Nice generalization. I wonder what would this amount to categories other than Set.

Answer (score 6):

No.

For example, take $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ to be
$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
2 & x=1\\
1 & x=2\\
x & x>2\\
\end{cases}$.

Assume that there is $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f=g\circ g$.

Notice that $g(1)\neq1$ since $g(1)=1\Rightarrow f(1)=g(g(1))=g(1)=1\neq f(1)$ and similarly $g(2)\neq 2$.
Also $g(1)\neq 2$ since $g(1)=2\Rightarrow f(1)=g(g(1))=g(2)\neq 2=f(1)$.
From here it follows that $f(g(1))=g(1)$ because $g(1)\neq 1,2$.

We also know that $g(1)\neq g(2)$ because $g(g(1))\neq g(g(2))$.

But we also deduce that $g(1)=f(g(1))=g(g(g(1)))=g(f(1))=g(2)$, which contradicts the previous line.

Comment: @azimut, indeed, actually while writing this answer I used the notation $t=g(1)$, which makes it even similar to your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Shay and Azimut have found the perfect counter-example, and I just want to say a word about how one might come up with such a counter-example.

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on $\{1, \dots, n\}$. A necessary condition for a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ to admit a square root is that it be *even*: indeed, the squares of $S_n$ all lie in the kernel of the sign $S_n \to \{\pm 1\}$.

With this in mind, the permutation of $\mathbf N$ which switches $1$ and $2$ is a natural candidate for a function which has no square root. Indeed, *if* one could speak of its sign, it should be negative. Unfortunately, one cannot speak of the sign of an arbitrary permutation of $\mathbf N$. One can, however, speak of the sign of a permutation which is almost everywhere the identity. Permutations of $\mathbf N$ which leave almost all elements fixed form a subgroup of the group of all permutations of $\mathbf N$, which identifies with the direct limit $\mathbf S_{\infty}$ of the direct system $S_1 \to S_2 \to S_3 \to \dots$. The sign homomorphisms are compatible with the maps of the direct system, and determine a sign homomorphism $\mathbf S_{\infty} \to \{\pm 1\}$. Azimut and Shay's map is an "odd" element of $\mathbf S_{\infty}$, and therefore cannot admit a square root *inside* $\mathbf S_{\infty}$.

Unfortunately, this is not sufficient to see that their map admits no square root, because there are permutations of $\mathbf N$ which are not in $\mathbf S_{\infty}$, but whose square is. Thus, one still needs to argue (as they do) that their map cannot admit a square root in the bigger group $S_{\mathbf N}$. But perhaps, it is still interesting to have this source of intuition!